# If I try to modify the current object within a function in a class in Python3.7, then why the changes aren't reflected outside the function call?

Tags: class, linked-list, pass-by-reference, python-3.7

The code that is given below, shows an object oriented implementation of a linked list in Python 3.7. Here I've defined a class called Node and under this class I've defined a function delete that takes two parameters : 'this' and 'x'. Here 'this' is the current/calling object and 'x' is the value that is to be searched and deleted from the linked list.

Now, the problem is when I pass such a value for 'x' so that its actually the first Node of the List, then as per the code, the below mentioned line is executed:
             this = this.next
so that the first node gets deleted, but when I display the List using the display() function after a successful call of the delete() function, then the list displayed still has the first node (i.e. first node was not deleted)

So Why its happening?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(this, data = None):
        this.data = data
        this.next = None

    def append(this, x):
        p = this
        if this.data == None:
            this.data = x
        else:
            while p.next != None:
                p = p.next
            p.next = Node(x)

    def search(this, x):
        p = this
        while p != None and p.data != x:
            p = p.next
        if p == None:
            return False
        elif p.data == x:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def delete(this, x):
        p = this
        if this.data == x:
            this = this.next
            return (True, x)
        else:
            while p.next.next != None and p.next.data != x:
                p = p.next
            if p.next.next == None and p.next.data == x:
                p.next = None
                return (True, x)
            elif p.next.data == x:
                p.next = p.next.next
                return (True, x)
            else:
                return (False, x)

    def display(this):
        p = this
        if p == None:
            print("Empty List")
        else:
            while p != None:
                print(p.data, end = " ")
                p = p.next
        print("\n")

print("Enter 1 to Append Data")
print("Enter 2 to Search Data")
print("Enter 3 to Delete Data if Exists")
print("Enter 4 to Display the List")
print("Enter 5 to Quit")
List = Node()

while True:
    print("Enter your Choice", end = " = ")
    choice = int(input())
    if choice == 1:
        x = int(input("Enter a No. to append = "))
        List.append(x)
    elif choice == 2:
        x = int(input("Enter a No. to Search = "))
        if List.search(x):
            print("Search SuccessFull")
        else:
            print("Search Unsucessfull")
    elif choice == 3:
        x = int(input("Enter a No. to Delete = "))
        (p, q) = List.delete(x)
        if p == True:
            print("Deleted = ", q)
        else:
            print("Not found : ", q)
    elif choice == 4:
        List.display()
    elif choice == 5:
        print("Good Bye")
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong Choice")

# ----- OUTPUT ------#

Enter 1 to Append Data
Enter 2 to Search Data
Enter 3 to Delete Data if Exists
Enter 4 to Display the List
Enter 5 to Quit
Enter your Choice = 1
Enter a No. to append = 20
Enter your Choice = 1
Enter a No. to append = 21
Enter your Choice = 1
Enter a No. to append = 22
Enter your Choice = 1
Enter a No. to append = 23
Enter your Choice = 1
Enter a No. to append = 24
Enter your Choice = 4
20 21 22 23 24 

Enter your Choice = 3
Enter a No. to Delete = 20
Deleted =  20
Enter your Choice = 4
20 21 22 23 24
```

See after deleting 20 
We expect a list of 21 22 23 24, but its not so!